# Como accedo a un array en el constructor?

Tags: c++

Declaro el tamaño del array con el constructor, pero después no se como sacar los valores desde otra función

```
class clase{
    clase(int i){
       float a[i]; 
    }

    void u (){
        ????
   }
};
```

Comment: Por favor, pon un ejemplo con código que sirva de ejemplo

Comment: Es que al ser tan básico pensé que no seria necesario

Comment: Tu conoces el problema y todos sus detalles y para ti puede ser algo básico, pero si no compartes toda esa información entonces nos queda inventarnos los huecos y eso puede hacer que la respuestas no sean exactas o correctas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder usar una variable dentro de un objeto, la misma debe estar definida en el ámbito de la clase, no de la función.

Las variables que declaras en el ámbito de una función desaparecen al finalizar la función.

```
class A
{
    int variable; // Variable accesible por todos los métodos de la clase

    A()
    {
      int variable2; // Variable local, solo es visible para el constructor  
    }
};
```

Ahora bien, en el caso de los arrays, no es posible darles un tamaño variable porque el tamaño de los mismos debe estar definido en el mismo momento en el que se declara el array ... el problema aquí es que en el momento de declarar el array no puedes saber el tamaño final del array:

```
class clase{
    float a[¿¿??];

    clase(int i){
       // float a[i]; 
    }
};
```

Lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es tirar de memoria dinámica:

```
class clase
{
    float *array;

public:
    clase(int length)
        : array{new float[length]}
    { }

    ~clase()
    { delete[] array; }

    void otraFunc()
    {
        array[0] = 123;
    }        
};
```

Comment: Gracias... pero "delete" que elimina? hasta que punto es imprescindible?

Comment: seria mucho pedir que me expliques porque ese proceso me da problemas con los arreglos multi dimensionales?

Comment: @WillFredo delete libera la memoria reservada por new.  Si no liberas la memoria, no podras reutilizarla hasta que no cierres el programa

Comment: @WillFredo si no se cómo estás intentando crear un array dimensional no puedo saber por qué te falla. Quizás debas publicar una nueva pregunta

Comment: .... exactamente igual pero mas otro corchete y otro asterisco

Comment: @WillFredo Los comentarios no están pensados para responder preguntas. Las preguntas, por otro lado, se hacen publicando preguntas. Cuando se publica una respuesta, no solo pretendo ayudarte a ti, sino también a cualquier otro que venga después con el mismo problema o uno similar. Piensa que si esto fuese un servicio de asesoría personalizado tendrías que pagar por él, pero aquí te regalamos parte de nuestro tiempo... no cuesta tanto seguir las normas

Comment: @WillFredo por otro lado, ya se cómo se declara un array **bi**dimensional, lo que no se es cómo lo estás usando tu exactamente. Me puedo hacer una idea ... pero puedo tener suerte y acertar ... o no. Ahí es donde entra tu participación publicando preguntas claras y bien explicadas